# Vkbottle не принимает приватные сообщения

Tags: python

Решил написать бота для вк и столкнулся с проблемой в Vkbottle:

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message

bot = Bot(token='токен')


@bot.on.private_message(text='Привет')
async def message_handler(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Привет!')

bot.run_forever
```

Почему он не принимает личные сообщения?
Версия Long Pool API 5.103

Comment: Это ошибка или ты забыл дописать вызов функции bot.run_forever()?

Comment: ошибка, ведь я уже все перепробывал